# Does the Warlock's Thought Shield effectively act like a Ring of Mind Shielding?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, warlock

> Ring of Mind Shielding (DMG, p. 191)
>
> > While wearing this ring, you are immune to magic that allows other creatures to read your thoughts, determine whether you are lying, know your alignment, or know your creature type. Creatures can telepathically communicate with you only if you allow it... (etc.)
>
> Thought Shield (PHB, p. 110)
>
> > Starting at 10th level, your thoughts can't be read by telepathy or other means unless you allow it... (etc.)

I mean in the sense that it protects the Warlock from lie, alignment, and creature type detection, not the "soul-transfer" stuff. How else would lies be detected magically without some form of mind-reading?

Answer (score 7):

**No**

Features only do what they say they do. Also, notice that the ring does no say anything like "read your thoughts and *thereby* determine whether you are lying", these are listed as separate things. Furthermore, consider that people might still be able to tell when you lie without reading your thoughts or any magic whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, I know that people can still distinguish lies through means other than magic. In my question, however, I was asking how else detecting lies _magically_ would not entail some form of mind-reading. Perhaps it's an altogether different magical effect?

Comment: @EnnoBennetra Magic is magic and not science. It only does what it says it does. No lie detecting magic to my knowledge mentions it as a telepathic effect. You can rationalize however you want.